# How do I stop SpamAssassin cron job from mailing me errors?

Tags: email, cron, spamassassin

I have a cron job for SpamAssassin to update, but it keeps sending me the errors. How can I stop the SpamAssasin job from emailing me?

This is the email that I get:

```
Subject: Cron <root@kizbit> /usr/share/spamassassin/sa-update.cron 2>&1 | tee -a /var/log/sa-update.log
UTF-16 surrogate 0xd800 at /usr/share/perl5/Pod/Simple/BlackBox.pm line 67.
UTF-16 surrogate 0xd800 at /usr/share/perl5/Pod/Simple/BlackBox.pm line 67.
UTF-16 surrogate 0xd800 at /usr/share/perl5/Pod/Simple/BlackBox.pm line 67.
http: GET 3.4 request failed: 400 URL must be absolute: 400 URL must be absolute 
error: no mirror data available for channel sought.rules.yerp.org
channel: MIRRORED.BY contents were missing, channel failed
http: GET 3.4 request failed: 400 URL must be absolute: 400 URL must be absolute 
error: no mirror data available for channel updates.spamassassin.org
channel: MIRRORED.BY contents were missing, channel failed
```

I tried editing `/etc/cron.d/sa-update` and changing this line

```
# 10 4 * * * root /usr/share/spamassassin/sa-update.cron 2>&1 | tee -a /var/log/sa-update.log
10 4 * * * root /usr/share/spamassassin/sa-update.cron 2>&1 >> /var/log/sa-update.log
```

I tried adding the line at the beginning of the file.

```
MAILTO=
```

I tried to view the crontab for the spam user:

```
# crontab -l -u spam
no crontab for spam
```

Since nothing worked and it still mails me, how can I stop it from mailing me?

CentOS release 6.10 (Final)